# .net6 There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

So i have been taking a course which was developed in .net 5 but I am using .net 6 to complete the project.

This error happens whenever I add the class library reference to my client .Csproj file

this is the actual error message

> Error NETSDK1082 There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'. Project_Client C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets 427

and this is what the solution was given by the instructor "that package cannot work with  Blazor WASM project you need to remove that reference." not sure exactly what was meant by this so I have tired the following

So Removed the following codes from "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets"  (this is what starts on line 427)

```
<ResolveRuntimePackAssets FrameworkReferences="@(FrameworkReference)"
 
                              ResolvedRuntimePacks="@(ResolvedRuntimePack)"
 
                              UnavailableRuntimePacks="@(UnavailableRuntimePack)"
 
                              SatelliteResourceLanguages="$(SatelliteResourceLanguages)"
 
                              DesignTimeBuild="$(DesignTimeBuild)">
 
      <Output TaskParameter="RuntimePackAssets" ItemName="RuntimePackAsset" />
 
    </ResolveRuntimePackAssets
>
```

and the project now builds and runs but get stuck on a loop - I have also tried to delete the file Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets from "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets" and same things happens

I have read another answer to have the shared files saved in both projects but they did add "which is not desirable of course" which is what i will be trying next.

Comment: The .NET SDK isn't broken. Trying to "fix" it only produces problems. The Blazor templates would never include a web *server* reference in the client project. Instead of trying to "fix" things, reinstall the .NET 6 SDK and actually use the .NET 6 templates to create your Blazor project

Comment: .NET 5 Blazor templates didn't include web app libraries in the client project either. Did you try to use a NuGet package or library built only for web apps in the Blazor WASM project? In any case people can't help you now - we can't guess what damage was done to the SDK.

Comment: `what i will be trying next` you'll get into more trouble. It sounds like you already broke the .NET 6 SDK. There's nothing wrong with the `Shared` project unless you explicitly added a reference to a library only usable by web apps. Don't do that.

Comment: Hi i didnt damage the SDK i have put things back in order (original state) which then allowed me to move forward but if you think i need to reinstall the .NET 6 SDK i can try that

Comment: In that case you need to solve the actual problem. It seems you created a hosted Blazor WASM project and added a web app reference to the `Shared` project. That project is meant to hold DTOs that are used by both the client SPA and server APIs. Did you add a reference to an ASP.NET Core assembly? Or added a NuGet package that does so? Please post the `.Shared.csproj` file

Comment: HI Panagiotis, so there is no Shared.Csproj (I think) let me explain so what happened is the course that i am following, started with the server, then we created the API  and then finally the client - the project has 4 different class library Business, Common, DataAcesss and Models but whenever I tired to add "project reference" on any of them for the client side, this error pops up and the only thing the instructor said was "that package cannot work with  Blazor WASM project you need to remove that reference" i dont understand what he meant by that - Again I really appreciate your inputs

Comment: All those are server-side projects. You can't add them to the SPA client, nor should you try. The data and business rules used in a client-side SPA are *very* different from the server-side Web API.

Comment: ohhhh I see, is it due to my project being in .net6 or have i messed up somewhere earlier you reckon?

Comment: No, the tutorial you try to follow has nothing to do with SPAs, whether they're written in Blazor or Angular. If you want to learn about Blazor WebAssembly find a Blazor WebAssembly tutorial

Comment: In fact, the projects/modules you'd use in an SPA are *very* different from a server-side web site. There's little or no data access, unless you mean accessing the server's local storage. The SPA can only talk to the server's APIs through HTTP. All the code will be packaged and delivered to the browser, so the number of code and projects should be kept to a minimum. Heavy logic and validation are performed on the server, not the client. Different modules are needed when you want to lazily load assemblies to reduce startup time

Comment: I just recently discovered the same thing. I started in .NET5, successfully moved to .NET6 but now, when I upgraded VS2022 to latest version 17.5.1 including .NET SDK 7.0.201 it can no longer compile with the same error as you had.